# Show, that series $\sum a_n$,where $a_n = \underbrace{\sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + \ldots + \sqrt{2}}}}}_{n\;\text{terms}}$ convergence

Tags: real-analysis, summation

Show, that series $\sum a_n$,where $a_n = \underbrace{\sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + \ldots + \sqrt{2}}}}}_{n\;\text{terms}}$ convergence.

Firstly, i prove that if $n \rightarrow \infty$ then $b_n = \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + \ldots + \sqrt{2}}} \rightarrow 2$

But, what to do next i dont know.

Comment: If so you solved the problem

Comment: Consider that $a^2_n = 2- a_{n-1}$.

Comment: @Opt Not true. There is only one $-$ in all of the nested roots.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg He only showed that $a_n\to 0$. He hasn't shown that $\sum a_n$ converges.

Comment: @Arthur yes, you are right. Like we cant say that $\sum\frac{1}{n}$ convergence

Comment: @Arthur  I did not see $\sum$

Comment: @Arthur Yes, I didn't see that:)

Comment: In fact, there is an explicit formula for $b_n$ namely $b_n = 2\cos (2^{-n-1} \pi)$. Use this formula, $a_n = \sqrt{2-b_{n-1}}$ and the standard limit $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^2} = \frac 12$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $\theta \in (0,\frac{\pi}{2})$, we have the half-angle formula for cosine and sine functions:

$$
\sqrt{2 + 2\cos\theta} = 2\cos\frac{\theta}{2}\quad\text{ and }\quad
\sqrt{2 - 2\cos\theta} = 2\sin\frac{\theta}{2}
$$

Since $\sqrt{2} = 2\sin\frac{\pi}{4} = 2\cos\frac{\pi}{4}$, it is easy to see

$$a_n \stackrel{def}{=}\underbrace{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\cdots \sqrt{2}}}}}_{n\text{ terms}} = 2\sin\frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}} < \frac{\pi}{2^n}$$

Notice $a_n$ are all positive, this means the partial sums $\sum_{n=1}^p a_n$ is monotonic increasing. Furthermore, the partial sum is bounded from above by that of a geometric sequence.

$$\sum_{n=1}^p a_n < \sum_{n=1}^p \frac{\pi}{2^n} < \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\pi}{2^n} = \pi$$

As a result, the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges to a number $\le \pi$.

Answer (score 0):

We can calculate a value of $a_n$ because
$$\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}=\sqrt{2\left(1+\cos\frac{\pi}{4}\right)}=2\cos\frac{\pi}{8}$$
and the rest is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Since $b_n$ is a dynamical sequence converging to an attracting fixpoint, it converges to $2$ exponentially. Since the function mapping $b_n$ to $a_n$ is differentiable there, $a_n$ also converges to its limit $0$ exponentially, and thus the series converges.

You can make this a precise without too much trouble :

$(a_{n+1}/a_n)^2 = (2-b_{n+1}) / a_n^2 = (2 - \sqrt{4-a_n^2})/a_n^2 = (4-4+a_n^2)/(a_n^2(2+\sqrt{4-a_n^2})) \\
= 1/(2 + \sqrt {4-a_n^2})$

Since $a_n$ converges to $0$, this converges to $1/4$, which proves that $(a_n)$ converges to $0$ exponentially (it is a $O((\frac 12 + \varepsilon)^n)$ for any $\varepsilon > 0$).